# OP (Overlall Position) Calculations for Queensland's post-secondary-entrance rankings

Tags: secondary-education

I am looking to calculate an OP Score (Overall Position). It is an outdated Queensland system of post-secondary-entrance rankings due to be phased out in 2018. None the less I am looking for **specific** information in regards to calculation an OP. The [basics from the Queensland Curriculum and Assessment Authority (QCAA)](http://www.qcaa.qld.edu.au/senior/tertiary-entrance/op) is of little help in actually calculating a score.

If anyone is knowledgeable in this area it would be of great help if you could outline the basic of such calculations.

The information I have:

- Subject Rankings (SA#, HA#, VHA#...)
- School QCS Average (~173)
- Position in each Subject (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th...)
- OAI cutoffs (124 = OP1, <120 = OP2....)

From my interpretation of the resources at hand (QCAA):

- A SAI is deductible from subject ranking and positioning
- A scaled SAI is deductible from School QCS 173
- An OAI is deductible from interschool scaling (Unknown process)

Any specifics on calculating an OP score will be of great help.

Comment: Previously asked at [Academia Stack Exchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/75585/64) where it was closed around an hour before this question was posted here.

Comment: It doesn't seem [on topic](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), unless there's some link I'm not seeing. Clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: I agree that the question doesn't seem on topic, and anyway, looking at the "Calculating OPs: The basic principles (PDF, 796.7 KB)" document linked from the question's link, it seems you would have to have the input data for the entire population that was being OPed, since, after all, the OP is supposed to reflect one's overall position within the given population of post-secondary students. It's **relative**, not **absolute**. [Disclaimer: I have never been to QLD and the only thing I know about the OP ranking is what I just read.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a question about mathematics education.